# How do I Start Eclipse project with GUI windows spaced out?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I'm running a large Java Eclipse project and when it starts up, I see 3 pop-up windows tiled on top of each other, as so:

[image]

I need to have them start up separated positions, as I'm always testing the program and dragging the windows. Can I somehow put them all in a bigger GUI window(pane)?

Comment: Can't you simply call setLocation on those windows?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet - setLocation ,, hmm I'm reading up that right now thanks!

Comment: and if you have called `pack()` or `setSize/setBounds` on the window, you can use their size to make them next to each other. Also it looks like you are calling setLocationByPlatform--> drop those calls

Comment: @GuillaumePolet - Thank You Very Much ! I'm almost there now, It should be working soon!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setLocation() method

```
windowName.setLocation(location_parameters);
```

passing the 'null' as an argument will make the window center.

There is another way,

> setLocationRelatedTo(item_to_relate)

method. this will locate them according to the existing things like JLabels, existing windows, etc.

Comment: it makes the window center itself only if it has already been "sized" by invoking `pack()` or `setSize()` or `setBounds()`

Answer (score 1):

> Can I somehow put them all in a bigger GUI window(pane)?

You presently have 3 `JFrame`s, I think.

You could change this to 3 `JPanel`s in one frame.

You would use a [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to arrange the 3 `JPanel`s the way you want.